# Multiprocessing using Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two functions which  are processing in parallel. I want to keep check  about functions that when are they running  and when finishing. How can I do that.I tried few things but it didn't work. My code looks like:

```py
q1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
q2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
p1 = Process(target = fun1, args = (arg1,arg2,q1))
p2 = Process(target = fun2, args = (arg1,arg2,q2))
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

Basically trying to get a message like: `'fun1 is running'`, and after execution: `'fun1 ended, total time= t'` and same for `fun2` as well.

Comment: What are you using q1 and q2 for?  You can pass information back to your main program through those.

Comment: Basically I'm storing result of the two fun in q1 and q1, which I have to return in end.

Comment: Because they are queues, you can pass more than just final answers through them, one way is to send dictionaries where the keys are the message types you are passing back.   However, if you just want to print diagnostic messages, @icebreaker454 has a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **use a decorator**

Wrap your functions in a decorator that would to the thing for you.

```py
import time

def timed(func):
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        print(f"{func.__name__} has started")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"{func.__name__} ended. Took: {end-start}s")
    
        return result
    return _wrapper


p1 = Process(target = timed(fun1), args = (arg1,arg2,q1))
p1.start()
```